# Credentials signup / login in Next.js

Tags: reactjs, authentication, session, next.js, next-auth

NextAuth documentation says for their Credentials provider that

> "It is intended to support use cases where you have an existing system
> you need to authenticate users against."

and also

> "The functionality provided for credentials based authentication is
> intentionally limited to discourage use of passwords due to the
> inherent security risks associated with them and the additional
> complexity associated with supporting usernames and passwords."

So I want to ask is that when making a new system which does not have existing users should we not use Username/Password login.
Most of the website I see have a registration page and then user can logs in using username / password. They may also have other options like login with Google etc but credentials is also present.

I'm confused is it really bad thing to use Credentials login(without the 2FA), and if it is not bad how can we right code for it in Next.js properly. Is it ok to save user session in context or are there any better ways ?